# How to loop for each table in one sheet VBA

Tags: excel, vba

im trying to generate lists of table and column to txt file from excel file.
my code just generate for all clumn until end of row because i have no idea how to define variable to limit looping each table :

here the code and excel data [image Excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqPrk.png)

```
Dim field As String
Dim table As String
Dim t As Integer
Dim f As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim myFile As String
Dim xStr As String

myFile = "D:\table.txt"

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    Open myFile For Output As #1

    table = """table_name"": """ & .Range("I2") & ""","
    Print #1, table

    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For f = 2 To lastrow
        field = """column_name"": [" & Chr(10) & """" & .Range("B" & f) & """" & Chr(10) & _
        "],"
        Print #1, field
    Next f

    Close #1


End With
```

I imagine the code like below(CMIIW the logic), but how to write this on vba:

```
for t = 1 to "count table on sheet (i dnt know how to define this value)"
  table = "tablename"
  Print #1, table

  for f = "first row table t + 1" to lastrow table t
    field= "fieldname"
    Print #1, field
  Next f
Next t
```

Base on answer of user11246173 i know how to loop as number of table count, 
but i still cant get the range of each specific cell like my code above.
Please help to resolve my code.

Anyone can please help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

In VBA, worksheet tables are called ListObjects. They are a collection that belongs to the parent worksheet and (among other properties) have a count and an index as do most other collection objects. Each ListObject has a number of ListColumns.

```
Option Explicit

Sub loopLO()

    Dim i As Long, c As Long

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        For i = 1 To .ListObjects.Count
            Debug.Print .ListObjects(i).Name
            For c = 1 To .ListObjects(i).ListColumns.Count
                Debug.Print .ListObjects(i).ListColumns(c)
            Next c
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: i think its work, but i need set format as table for each table in my excel, any automatic way to format as table in each table?

Comment: Creating a ListObject is not 'set format as table'. Record yourself applying Ctrl+T to some cells.

Comment: i implement your code to my code, but i still dnt know how to get first row id from table (i), becasue i need get table name at cell I2 dan I10 like image i attach. i think i need code like table = """table_name"": """ & .Range("I" & .table(i).first row (idk how to code this) + 1) & ""","

Comment: Try worksheets("sheet1").listobjects("table1").range.cells(1).address

Comment: i still not got the poin. i want to conacate to other string so i need more specific row id, i tried Print #1, .ListObjects(i).ListColumns(2,2) 2,2 mean i tried to get row B2

Comment: with your code Print .ListObjects(i).ListColumns(c) i just get header name only. not the content of each row from table

Comment: If a ListObjec has a property called ListColumns then maybe it has another property called ListRows.

Comment: No, I mean how to get the specific row,? example i want to get cell B4